# Cordova iOS; see changes on save

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm building an iOS app using Cordova. When I make a change I need to rebuild the app to see the changes even if I refresh using Safari.

Do you know of a way I can see the changes I've made without the need to rebuild?

Comment: I don't think this functionality exists out of the box in Cordova. Yet the Ionic Framework [offers a `--livereload` option](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/), which sounds like the feature your looking for